# "Stars and Bars" summation identity

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

Can anybody help me solve this problem?
I don't even know where to start or how to interpret this.

Proof for all $1 \leq k \leq n$ that the folowing identity holds:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
n+k-1 \\
n-1
\end{pmatrix} =
\sum_{i=1}^k \begin{pmatrix}k-1 \\ i-1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} n \\ i \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

This problem is in fact a homework assignment, so it would be kind if the solution isn't spoiled right away. There is one hint given in the assignment that says that for k identical objects and n different colors ($k \geq n$) the amount of different color combinations (you may repeat colors) when using every color at least once, is equal to: $\begin{pmatrix} k-1 \\ n-1 \end{pmatrix}$

I hope that anybody can assist me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you looking for an algebraic or a combinatorial proof?

Comment: A combinatorical proof

Comment: then generally the approach is to consider what set the LHS is counting, and what set (or in this case disjoint union of products of sets) the RHS is counting, and then establish that the sets are the same and merely counted a different way i.e. that there is a bijection between the sets.

Comment: Oh, i see! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite $\binom{n}{i}$ as $\binom{n}{n-i}$ and use a combinatorial proof of Vandermonde's identity.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Well, the RHS is choosing some color ($i$ of them) and coloring $k$ objects with those $i$ colors. Using the hint given, every of the $i-$th colors chosen is used **at least once**. But notice that you choose the colors, that means the other $n-i$ were not used. So, if you were to consider the $n$ colors at a whole, then you are relaxing the condition of **at least once** to no restriction at all. What is, then, the LHS?